# If $1 - F_{-X}(-x)$ is the CDF of $X$, what is $f_X(x)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ has CDF $1 - F_{-X}(-x)$ where $F_{-X}(-x) = P(-X \leq -x)$, the CDF of $-X$.
What is the PDF of $X$?

I am struggling a bit with the negative signs in the argument of $F_{-X}$. Traditionally, I know that $f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F_X(x)$. Here we have that $F_X(x) = 1 - F_{-X}(-x)$, so
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(1 - F_{-X}(-x)) = -\frac{d}{dx}F_{-X}(-x) = -f_{-X}(-x) * \frac{d(-x)}{dx} = -f_{-X}(-x) * -1 = f_{-X}(-x)
$$

So is the PDF of $X$ just $f_X = f_{-X}(-x)$?

Comment: The only typo I see is your last line: it should be $f_{X}(x) = f_{-X}(-x)$. Otherwise it seems fine. I'm not sure why one would use this formula, though.

Comment: @Clarinetist Just corrected the typo. Thanks for catching that. What is wrong with the formula?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the formula. I just don't know in what situation I would use it in is all I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

> $$\begin{align}F_X(x) &=1-F_{-X}(-x)\\[2ex]f_X(x) &= \frac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm dx}(1 - F_{-X}(-x)) \\[1ex]&= -\frac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm dx}F_{-X}(-x) \\[1ex]&= -f_{-X}(-x) \cdot \frac{d(-x)}{dx} \\[1ex]&= -f_{-X}(-x) \cdot( -1) \\[1ex]&= f_{-X}(-x)\end{align}$$
>
> So is the PDF of $X$ just $f_X(x) = f_{-X}(-x)$?

Yes.  If $X$ is an absolutely continuous random variable, that is the case.

Note: $F_X(x)=1-F_{-X}(-x)$ requires $X$ to be such.  $$\begin{align}F_X(x)&=\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)\\&=\mathsf P(X<1) &&\text{if }\mathsf P(X<x)=\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)\\&=1-\mathsf P(X\geqslant x)\\&=1-\mathsf P(-X\leqslant-x)\\&= 1-F_{-X}(-x) \end{align}$$